# Silverlight snapping to grid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, designer, silverlight-toolkit

I am in the process of creating a visual designer for which i need the snap to grid functionality like the one provided by mocking Bird ( [Demo](https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/) ). Is there any project, usercontrol or resources that will help me develop the same in silverlight as quick as possible.

I have been able to accomplish the drag and drop operation from the toolbox (Listbox ) to the canvas at the center of the designer screen. But the snap to grid and grid functionality is  superb to have in the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MouseMove routine, you need to do an additional adjustment to allow for snapping.

```
void MainImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseMoveEventArgs args){

    // ... assume you have calculated newX and newY already

    adjustSnap(ref newX, ref newY);

    // ... position your element

}

bool _isSnapOn = true;

void adjustSnap(ref double x, ref double y)
{
    const double gridWidth = 100;
    const double gridHeight = 100;

    if (_isSnapOn) 
    {

        if (x % gridWidth < gridWidth/2)
            x -= x % gridWidth;
        else
            x += (gridWidth - x % gridWidth);

        if (y % gridHeight < gridHeight / 2)
            y -= y % gridHeight;
        else
            y += (gridHeight - y % gridHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Logic seems worthy of try, will put it in working now and get back